# Create sound effect with Tone.js notes?

Tags: javascript, audio, tone.js

How can I create one of [these](https://www.pond5.com/de/sound-effects/item/53466654-match-three-games-achievement-arpeggiated-notes) sound effects with Tone.js notes

Is this even possible? When given are these notes:
"C","C#","Db","D","D#","Eb","E","E#","Fb","F","F#","Gb","G","G#","Ab","A","A#","Bb","B","B#","Cb"...
Can I now somehow use tone.js to create a sound effect like "Tada!"? I think it needs more than just the notes/tones, it needs also somehow pitching and time manimulation?

Simple C tone played for 400ms:

```
polySynth.triggerAttack("C");
setTimeout(x=>polySynth.triggerRelease("C"),400);
```

Here a working [Jsfiddle with Tone.js](https://jsfiddle.net/yotammann/zj0qsupt/) to experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a very experienced ear, but most of these sound like major chords (base, third, fifth) to me, some with an added octave. For example, C4, E4, G4, C5:

```js
const chord = ["C4", "E4", "G4", "C5"];
const duration = 0.5;
const delay = 0.05;
const now = Tone.now();
for (let i = 0; i < chord.length; i++) {
  const note = chord[i];
  polySynth.triggerAttackRelease(note, duration, now + i * delay);
}
```

If you want to randomize the root note, it might be useful to work with frequencies directly, instead of note names. The A above middle C is usually taken as 440 Hz, and each successive semi-tone above that is a factor of `Math.pow(2, 1/12)` higher:

```
const rootFrequency = 440;
const chordSemitones = [0, 4, 7, 12];
const duration = 0.5;
const delay = 0.1;
const now = Tone.now();
for (let i = 0; i < chordSemitones.length; i++) {
  const pitch = rootFrequency * Math.pow(2, chordSemitones[i] / 12);
  polySynth.triggerAttackRelease(pitch, duration, now + i * delay);
}
```